# Are the results from Microsoft SSRS in real-time from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

From my understanding MS SSRS is a data warehouse product. Its data is only as new as the last refresh. However, 3rd party support insists that SSRS results are in real-time.

If I am using a SQL Server view as a data source, are the SSRS results in real-time (ie whenever someone reads a SSRS report, it pulls it from SQL Server); or is it stored within SSRS and only updated with a refresh?

Comment: it is, as you call it, "real time" - i.e. you execute the report, it uses the current data from the database - perhaps you're conflating the fact that SSRS reports themselves (i.e. the layout etc) are stored "within SSRS" as you put it.

Comment: @JaromandaX See the answer from Ben Thul. There are more options for querying data than just always hitting SQL Server directly. If you were always immediately querying SQL Server, it would defeat the entire purpose of having a data warehouse.

Comment: well that's why I made it a comment not an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/set-report-processing-properties?view=sql-server-ver16) on how to run the report. Doing a copy/paste summary from the docs to here for posterity:

- On demand - You can specify that a report query a data source each time a user runs the report.
- On demand from cache - With this approach, if ten users open the report, only the first request results in report processing. The report is subsequently cached, and the remaining nine users view the cached report.
- From snapshots - A report snapshot is a report that contains layout information and data that is retrieved at a specific point in time.

So you may be right but third party support may also be right! You'll need to look at the properties of the relevant reports in SSRS to see how they're configured.